# Car won't start after changing spark plugs - 2002 Lancer

Tags: starting, mitsubishi

I recently changed my spark plugs in my 02 Lancer and now I'm having an issue getting it to start. I don't know if it's related to the spark plugs at all or just a coincidence because I was able to drive it with no problems twice after doing so, about 30 miles both times.

It doesn't seem like a battery issue because all accessories work although I won't rule it out. After turning the key, it makes kind of a 'clunk' noise for a second and then stops turning completely. No clicking. I thought maybe it wasn't getting any fuel but the same thing happens with about a quarter tank.

Here's a video that I hope describes the issue much better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rudGk245HQE&feature=youtu.be

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accessories use far less amps than what the vehicle demands when it trys to start.

Check your battery with a multimeter if you're under 12.6V you'll likely need to charge the battery and then try starting.

You could also try jump starting it.

It's more likely that the battery is weak, rather than something major has happened.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You are correct, charged the battery up and it started. It's an older battery so not too surprising. Thanks!